# Generate report from Interaction with custom model data

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I need to generate report from the custom model data saved with the interaction.

I created a custom event with custom model and then trigger the action from the code based on the user behavior.

For example, when the interaction is saved in database, the event is saved liked that:

```
[
   {  
      "@odata.type":"#Feedback",
      "CustomValues":[

  ],
  "Data":"25b3ad4e-21f9-4cd9-af0f-d5dc3f40e0bd",
  "DataKey":"newsletterid",
  "DefinitionId":"2b9cdda6-aa15-4df3-a305-4883a2f16cf4",
  "Id":"2b9cdda6-aa15-4df3-a305-4883a2f16cf4",
  "Text":"Signed up for newsletter",
  "Timestamp":"2018-07-27T11:14:33.7989090Z",
  "emailAddress":"test@test.com",
  "feedback":"happy"
   }
]
```

I need a report that get the users with their feedback from the above custom model.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please be more specific what type of report you need. Can you just write a search query for xConnect and export search results?

Comment: Update the question with an example

Comment: Do you want to know how to execute a search against xConnect or are you looking for how to build a custom Experience Analytics report?

Comment: I am new to Xconnect so i was thinking of creating custom analytics report, but could you please provide more details about search in xconnect?